# Creating and saving a text file for a Battleship Game in Python

Tags: python

I have been working on the same Battleship game for quite a while now and am getting to the end stages. Now I need to have the game save the top five scores in a text file using the function `def saveScore`. I then need it to read the file that I just created and load the scores into the Python code using `try` and `except` for file open and close. I don't know how to get Python to recognize my variable `score` because I believe it's only local. Here's what I have. I do not know how to use pickle.

```
def main():
    board=createBoard()
    printBoard(board)
    s = [[21,22,23,24,25],
    [45,55,65,75],
    [1,2,3],
    [85,86,87],
    [5,15],
    [46,56]]
    playBattleship(s,board)
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pickle is a lower level way to serialize a python object out to a file, and then read the format back again into an object. If you want a bit of a higher level interface that might be easier for you to use naturally, try looking at the `shelve` module: http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#example

You can treat it like a dictionary, and just append and save your scores. It will save to a file by pickling under the hood.

```
import shelve

# open a shelve file. writeback=True makes it save
# on the fly
d = shelve.open('temp.file', writeback=True)
if not d.has_key('scores'):
    d['scores'] = []

print d['scores']
# []

# add some score values
d['scores'].append(10)
d['scores'].append(20)
d.close()

# next time, open the file again. It will have
# the 'scores' key. Though you should probably check
# for it each time in case its a first run.
d = shelve.open('temp.file', writeback=True)
print d['scores']
#[10, 20]

# sort the list backwards and take the first 5 top scores
topScores = sorted(d['scores'], reverse=True)[:5]
```

Comment: Didn't know about the shelve module myself, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @twaddington: Sure. I don't think its used too widely. Its mostly a convenience for avoiding just pickling your own objects as needed.

Comment: The only problem is that I have to use try and except so I cannot use this code. Can you look at what I posted and see if you can make any sense of it?

Comment: @user1329880: 1) try except should have no impact whatsoever on your ability to use this example. 2) You should not be wrapping 15+ lines of code in a generic catch-all except block.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way for you to do this would be to use Pickle. Using the "load" and "dump" functions you can easily save/load the score object.

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

```
import pickle

def saveScore(score):
    pickle.dump(score, 'topfive2.txt')

def loadScore():
    return pickle.load('topfive2.txt')
```

Comment: this code is too advanced for me im not sure how it works let me post what I just fixed

Comment: You should just have to put the "import" statement at the top of your python file, above "def createBoard" and then replace your "saveScore" with the one I posted

Comment: You might have to expand this example to account for multiple scores. The OPs `score` is an int. This would only save an single one. Maybe show the OP how to save and recall a list?

Comment: The only problem is that I have to use try and except so I cannot use this code. Can you look at what I posted and see if you can make any sense of it?

Comment: @user1329880: Why are you commenting on all the answers suggesting the code is not useable because you **must** use a try except? You should explain in your question why it is you are wrapping this whole thing in a blanket catch-all exception block

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing files in Python is [pretty straightforward](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
# Opening a file for writing will return the file handle f
f = open('/tmp/workfile', 'w')

# You can then write to the file using the 'write' method
f.write('Hello world!\n')

# To read your data back you can use the 'read' or 'readlines' methods

# Read the entire file
str = f.read()

# Read the file one line at a time
line = f.readline()

# Read the file into a list
list = f.readlines()
```

If you want to store more data than just the last score, you might consider creating a SQLite3 database. Python has good [built-in support](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) for SQLite3. This is a cross-platform filesystem database. The database is just a regular text file on disk but it supports many of the SQL operations you'd expect from a database.

Comment: well now i have it saving the scores but i want them to be put in on their own lines. can you help with this?

Comment: @user1329880: `f.write("%s\n" % score)`

Comment: The "\n" is a special newline character that should indicate that the next item should be on its own line. Think of it link when you hit the "return" or "enter" key you are actually inserting an invisible newline character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline